# Highcharts Gauge not showing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using Angular and Higcharts to visualize some data. I have gotten many of the other Highchart components working, now I want to use the gauges. I went to the Highcharts website and used the example at their demo section. Unfortunately this is not working.
For some reason the gauge is blank but the other parts of my component shows up. Example below: [image]

My code looks like this:

---

### TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-speedo',
  templateUrl: './speedo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./speedo.component.scss']
})
export class SpeedoComponent implements OnInit {

  chartOptions: any;

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartRef: Highcharts.Chart;
  updateFromInput = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myChart();
  }

  chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = (chart) => {
    this.chartRef = chart;
  };

  myChart(){
    this.chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor:
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickAmount: 2,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
      }


}

    setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(
      new Event('resize')
    );
    }, 300);
   }

}
```

---

### HTML file

```
<p>speedo works!</p>

<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
  [(update)]="updateFromInput"
  [callbackFunction]="chartCallback">
</highcharts-chart>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code. How can I fix it so that the gauge actually shows up?

If anyone can recommend any other package I can use to show real time data on a gauge I would appreciate it. This package should be easy to use, or at least have more resources than Highcharts where one can find tutorials an so on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few glitches:

1. The `highcharts-more` module is missing. Import it at the begging

```
import HC_more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
HC_more(Highcharts);
```

2. Your demo was not working simply because there was nothing to show.
   All you have to do to fix this is to set the `data` in the `series` object.
   Remember to always add the series type for each series.

```
   series: [
      {
        type: "gauge",
        data: [80]
      }
    ]
```

Also, I highly recommend Highhcarts official documentation where you might find more examples and descriptions.

**API:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular
**Demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gauge

Comment: Thank you for the help, but when I add HC_more(Highcharts); I get the following error: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.

Comment: Which version of Highcharts do you use?

Comment: Currently im using:"highcharts": "^8.2.2",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.8.0",

Comment: You have the latest version (for this day). Do you get this locally or are you able to recreate this in online code editor?

Comment: It is locally. When I add it to my Angular project on local PC